# How to implement Chaincode to Query all blocks transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I want to deploy chain code to extract transactions from all blocks in the network. Does the QSCC query chain code should include INIT and INVOKE method or just only query function.

Please help me to understand in depth.

I referred the below GitHub query, but i am confused with INIT and INVOKE in the query.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/scc/qscc/query.go

Answer (score 0):

Every chaincode, should always implements the **Chaincode interface** in particular the **Init and Invoke functions**, so we need to mention these two functions. according to your question, if you want to only query the ledger then you can keep these functions empty as you like or implement query as an invoke function

Refer : [Chaincode interface](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/73d38948c4400a26db31c9967b582fc3b7fe0318/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L17)